# “Installation Failed” when installing Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework, matlab

The operating system of my laptop is **Windows7x64**. Whenever I install **MatlabR2013b** on it, this message is shown at the end of installation process:

> Your installation may require additional configuration steps.
>
> 1.The following products require a [supported compiler](http://it.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html?sec=win64#matlab) :
>
> MATLAB Compiler 5.0
>
> MATLAB Builder NE 4.2
>
> MATLAB Builder JA 2.3
>
> MATLAB Builder EX 2.4
>
> Simulink Coder 8.5
>
> xPC Target 5.5
>
> MATLAB Coder 2.5
>
> 2.To configure Real-Time Windows Target you must type rtwintgt -setup in a MATLAB command window.

About the first part of the message above, I viewed the provided link and I understood that I should install **Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1** and **Java Development Kit (JDK) 1.7** for the above components to be executable.
There's no problem with **JDK** installation but whenever I try to install **SDK** downloaded from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/0/F10113F5-B750-4969-A255-274341AC6BCE/GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso), it encounters the following error:

[image]

> A problem occurred while installing selected Windows SDK components.
>
> Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has
>   reported the following error: Fatal error during installation.
>
> Please attempt to resolve the problem and then start Windows SDK setup
>   again. If you continue to have problems with this issue, please visit
>   the SDK team support page at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=130245.
>
> Click the View Log button to review the installation log.
>
> To exit, click Finish.

**What is the problem and what should I do?**
I have [searched a little](http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1) but I have neither **Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 SP1 (version greater than 10.0.30319)** nor **.NET Framework 4.5 (also bundled with Visual Studio 2012 or later)** installed on my computer

[image]

**Then what do you think my problem is?

What should I do to fix it?**

About the second part I have asked [another question](https://superuser.com/q/970184/247416).

---

I tried to install it again. This time it produced the following error:
[image]

I've a shared the [log file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_9vCAvXd5kMzMwOXFaelBONFk/view?usp=sharing). It's a text file but it is shown as an audio file when downloading. Please open it with Notepad.

Comment: click on "View log" and share the log file.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've done what you said

Comment: The file you shared isn’t public.

Comment: @DanielB Is this OK now?

Comment: Yes. Funny how Google Drive thinks it’s an MP3 file. :D

Comment: Oh yeah, you already have a supported compiler installed because you have VS2010.

Comment: @sepideh Are you sure, during the installation of MS Visual Studio 2010 ultimate, the setup wizard has "x64 Compilers and Tools" option enabled/checked ??

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss well I've installed `VS2010` months ago but I think I always check all of the features to be installed also as seen in this picture [as seen in this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AUpSm.png) I have Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010(version = 10.0.30319) installed on my computer but because the version is equal to 10.0.30319 and not greater than 10.0.30319, I didn't think that the problem might be this according to [How do I install Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1?](http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll just “quote” [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032807/1025421) on Stack Overflow. There are other relevant answers next to it, too.

Too clarify: In your case, there’s an “affected” version of the VC++ 2010 x64 Redistributable installed.

---

This is a known issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426

**CAUSE**

> This issue occurs when you install the Windows 7 SDK on a computer
>   that has a newer version of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable
>   installed.

**RESOLUTION**

> To resolve this issue, you must uninstall all versions of the Visual
>   C++ 2010 Redistributable before installing the Windows 7 SDK.  You may
>   have one or more of the following products installed:
>
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable
> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable
>
> After uninstalling the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
>   Redistributable products, you may install the Windows 7 SDK.  After
>   installing the Windows 7 SDK, you may then reinstall the newer version
>   of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable products, in order to restore
>   the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable products to their original state.

[image: uninstallation picture]

Comment: Regarding [my other question](http://superuser.com/q/970184/247416) and the fact that I have installed **JDK**, and I have **VS2010** as a newer version of the supported compilers, I will have no problem in using [MATLAB Product Family](http://it.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html?sec=win64#matlab) and [Simulink Product Family](http://it.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html?sec=win64#simulink) and there's no need to uninstall **VS 2010** and install **SDK** and then reinstall **VS2010**. Right?

Comment: so why does matlab2013b produce [the following error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RkJ96.png) after installation? Because I've been struggling with this issue for about 1 year. Whenever I wanted to process **MEX-file**s with matlab, I had to borrow my friends' laptop. This time I want to know the cause and solve the problem forever. So there's no action needed? Won't I have problem in using [Matlab Features](http://it.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html?sec=win64#simulink) in the future if I don't install **SDK7.1**? (regarding that I have a newer version of it as **VS2010**)

Comment: It’s not an *error* message (as far as I can tell) and it says “may”. I don’t have MATLAB, so I can’t help you with it. In this case, the Windows SDK is merely a means to get C++ compilers, which you already have. If MATLAB won’t work, you should contact their support.

Comment: so for the time being no further action is needed

Comment: Just one more question! As you see in [the picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zWc3n.png) I have `VC++ 2010 x64 Redistributable` installed on my device but not `VC++ 2010 x86 Redistributable`. Should I install that seperately? I think they both are installed when installing `VS2010` but I don't now why it is not installed on my device regarding the fact that I always check up all the options when installing `VS2010`? Anyway, maybe they have been uninstalled when uninstalling other programs in the computer!

Comment: If a program requires a redistributable, it will install it. Well, it should, anyway. It won’t harm to install them by hand, but it’s usually not required.