# Further actions message after installing Matlab R2015a, Are they all needed?

Tags: installation, java, compile, matlab, runtime

At the final step of installing `Matlab R2015a` on my `Win7x64` machine, I've come up with the following message.

- What is this?
- Should all of these steps be done?

> Your installation may require additional configuration steps.
>
> 1. The following products require a [supported compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_scl_1_R2015a_win64):
>      Simulink Coder 8.8
>      Simulink Real-Time 6.2
>      MATLAB Coder 2.8
> 2. After this installation is complete, you should continue with your configuration of the  MATLAB Distributed Computing Server as outlined
>      in the instructions obtained from [www.mathworks.com/distconfig](http://www.mathworks.com/distconfig).
> 3. Important:    Before you can use MATLAB Production Server, you must set up your environment.
>      a. Download and install the [MATLAB Runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_mps_mcr_pi_R2015a_win64)
>
>    - Install the MATLAB Runtime in the default location
>    - Use version R2012b (v8.0) or later of the MATLAB Runtime
>
>    b. At the system command line, run mps-setup from the script folder.
>      The script folder is  located at **C:\Program
>      Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\script**.
>      c. For detailed instructions, download the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_mps_qsg_pi_R2015a_win64).
> 4. MATLAB Compiler 6.0 requires a [supported compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_scl_4_R2015a_win64) for creation
>      of Excel add-ins
> 5. MATLAB Compiler SDK 6.0 requires the following:
>      ● [.NET framework](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_scl_5_R2015a_win64) for creation of .NET assemblies and deployable archives with Excel
>      integration
>      ● a [supported
>      compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_scl_5_R2015a_win64) for creation
>      of COM components, C and C++ Shared libraries
>      ● a [Java
>      JDK](http://www.mathworks.com/pi_scl_5_R2015a_win64) for creation of
>      Java packages

Comment: That depends on what you are going to use matlab for. Only you can answers that question.

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't tell it exactly now. For example I didn't need running MEX files but about 2 years ago, I had a project which involved running MEX files and Matlab didn't recognize my C++ compiler which was installed through installation of Visual Studio 2010 on my machine so I was forced to borrow one of my friends' laptop. As a final question can I install the above product whenever I need? Or they should be installed right after installation of MATLAB R2015a?

Comment: You should be able to install them later, but it will do no harm to install them now in case you need them in the future (other than using up disk space, of course).

Comment: @DavidPostill Just another question, I already have `.NET Framework 4.5`, `.NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack`, `Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate`, `Java SE Development Kit ` installed on my machine and also [I cannot install Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 because of having a newer version of Visual C++ 2010 redistributable installed](http://superuser.com/a/970314/247416) so doesn't matlab recognize these during installation in order not to recommend me install those products again?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use matlab.